# Python class property and PyCharm debugger

Tags: python

I have a class in Python that has a defined Property() function that fetches a Pandas DataFrame. When running in debugger mode in PyCharm, if I go in the self of that class and I look into the property attribute that fetches the data, I will see the Pandas DF although the code *never* called that property that fetches the data.

In debugger mode, does PyCharm execute the @property functions when we look into them *or* are these property attributes executed directly when a class is instantiated?

Comment: Accessing the attribute executes the method, that's *why* you write a `@property`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Perfect that answers my question! It is only because I went into the self object in debugger.